# Kotlin app not routing SMS messages from senders with alphabetical names to Appwrite Database

Tags: kotlin, broadcastreceiver, appwrite

I'm developing an Android application in Kotlin that intercepts incoming SMS messages and routes them to an Appwrite Database. However, I'm encountering an issue where messages from senders with alphabetical names, such as "DENTIST", are not being routed to the database as expected. Example are messages from telco carriers and organisations

I need assistance in identifying and resolving the issue causing messages from senders with alphabetical names to not be routed to the Appwrite Database. Additionally, I want to ensure that the solution maintains the efficiency and reliability of the message routing process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.